# Control Panel - Apply different theme for two different pages

Tags: liferay-theme, control-panel

I have created control panel theme following bootstrap standards. For some reason, we are using liferay 6.1 which doesn't provide responsiveness and hence has to be taken care of. 
As we know control panel contains many pages e.g: MyAccount, User Administartion e.t.c. 
As of now,these pages are looking fine with the old theme(non-bootstrap).
As and when I update these pages to bootstrap standards, I want to be able to apply bootstrap control panel theme for them.

Question here is - How do I apply old theme for MyAccount Page and bootstrap theme for User Administration page. Is there some property file that I need to update?
I did my research but couldn't find anything substantial.
Please let me know if I need to be more specific about the query.

Comment: Yes, you need to be a little more specific please

Comment: I think MyAccount,User Administartion are not pages,AIK, for entire control-panel only one theme is there, what ever you are seeing are jsp pages only, when you clik on those buttons it will open jsp pages, check the urls if you want.